# Is this a good review audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just failed a Low Quality Posts audit. Huh. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/2229290).

Here's the thing: It looked OK to me - it answered the question. Why was it bad?

I can't see it anymore - you might need to be 10k to see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks to be a spam-like post based on how it was locked-deleted by Community. Not exactly obvious spam, probably not the best audit either:

[image: You've been struck by a smooth criminal, or not]

[You've been caught by the algorithm which chooses review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176425/incorrect-review-audits-false-positives?rq=1). We see a decent number of these questions.

Comment: Didn't look like spam to me - could you post a screenshot so I could see it again?

Comment: I qualified my statement with why I said it was "spam like", I had meant that it was locked-deleted like a spam flagged post. Not because I passed any judgement on it.

Comment: OK, makes more sense now. I couldn't see the Community actions (it was an audit...), and I guess I was too lazy to check the links. Still, it's quite borderline - it answers the question. Do we have problems with users linking to their own site after actually answering the questions?

Comment: @Undo - We do have a problem if it is the third such account this user has created to promote their website. That answer also doesn't specifically address the question asked, and the link adds little to the explanation. Some people treat Stack Overflow as a cheap traffic source for their ad-supported blogs or consulting sites, and we try to discourage that behavior.

Comment: @BradLarson OK, thanks.